# Which collections are supported by Hibernate @ManyToMany annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I used `@ManyToMany` annotation on a Set and it worked fine.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="stud_course_map",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="stud_id ")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="course_id")} )
public Set<Course> getEnrolledCourses() {
    return enrolledCourses;
}
```

When I used `ArrayList` instead of `Set` it throws exception:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non
>   collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements:
>   com.kaushik.winnersoft.data.Student.enrolledCourses

Is `ArrayList` not supported? Which all collection are supported by `@ManyToMany` annotation?

Comment: FWIW, other JPA providers support a full range of declared Collection type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The supported interfaces are:

```
java.util.Set
java.util.List
java.util.Collection
```

You get the exception because you have used a concrete implementation of one of those interfaces. Always define the `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToMany` using an interface as given above and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList **is** supported but you have to write it like **this**:

```
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead of

```
private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>(); //gives an error
```